# Is there a limited amount of characters when using Parse.com REST API

Tags: php, android, rest, parse-platform

I have a homemade web interface with several text and text area input fields. The primary text field are being sent to Parse in a php script via REST API. It works brilliant until I input approximately more than 3.000 characters in one of the textarea input fields.

When below approx. 3.000 characters, everything works fine. When above approx. 3.000 characters, the data gets sent to parse, and I can see it among the other push messages in my dashboard with a green check mark in "status", but the push notification is NOT being sent to any of the subscribed devices!

I'm using it for sending out news articles, so it is a must to be able to send whole articles above approx. 3.000 characters.

Is there any limitations in relation to the amount of characters to be sent or anything similar?

Does anyone know something that can help me or has any suggestions to how I can resolve this issue?!

The Parse parts of my script:

```
/*
  * PUSHING THE ARTICLE NOTIFICATION TO DEVICES SUBSCRIBING TO SPECIFIC CHANNELS(S)
  */

 $url = PUSH_URL;
 $appId = PUSH_APP_ID;
 $restKey = PUSH_REST_KEY;
 $channels = array($channelArray);

 $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
 );

 $objectData = json_encode(array(
        "data" => array(
            "id" => $id ,
            "watchTitle" => stripslashes($watchTitle) ,
            "title" => $textTitle ,
            "alert" => $textSubtitle ,
            "mainText" => $textMain ,
            "imgUrl" => $imgUrl ,
            "uri" => "http://watch.jgskytte.com/parse/article.php?p=" . $id ,
        ),
        "channels" => $channels ,
 ));

 $rest = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
 curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $objectData);  
 curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response = curl_exec($rest);
 echo $response;

 curl_close($rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

> There's no explicit limit on string length, but Parse Objects are limited to 128k. Otherwise, you should use a Parse File.

This is probably occurring because you're hitting the maximum length limit for a URL. To get around this, you can use a POST request instead which will send the query string as part of the HTTP request body, which has no such length limit.

Since Parse's REST API expects this query to be sent as a GET request, you will need to pass an additional header to let Parse know to treat this POST as a GET:

`X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have added some code to my questions above. Could you maybe give me some specifics to what to do in my code?